# Spring cli: command not valid

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to use `encrypt` command:

```
$ spring encrypt mysecret --key foo
```

It's working right.

However, I'm getting this error message when I perform: `spring encrypt MySecret? --key foo`

> zsh: no matches found: MySecret?

Comment: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/433 have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved that installing `spring-cloud-cli`:

```
spring install org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cli:1.0.3.RELEASE
```